# Regex search for more than one instance of any of these characters "+", "-", ".", "%", "/", "*"

Tags: regex, vb.net

The following regex will match an array with two decimal points in it, but is it possible for the regex string to also match if there are more than one `+` too, or the other characters in the title?

```
.{0,}\.{1}.{0,}\.{1}
```

Sample test cases:

123.312.1 - successful

123..12 - successful

123.512 - unsuccessful

+23232+ - successful

+2323% - unsuccessful

Comment: Are you aware that `.` matches any character in a regex? To explicitly match a `.`, you have to escape it like `\.`.

Answer (score 0):

At a basic level, you can use character sets thusly:

```
[+-.%/*]+
```

...which works fine for .NET, but Regex101.com wants the slash escaped thusly:

```
[+-.%\/*]+
```

...which will match one or more of any of the characters "+-.%/*".

Is that what you're asking?

Otherwise, can you give a more concrete example?

EDIT. Here's an expression that matches a string that has at least two occurrences of the characters you mentioned. It satisfies the test cases, but let me know if it's really what you're looking for:

```
(.*[+-.%/*]){2,}.*
```

ADDITIONAL EDIT. Adjusted so that it only matches when two like operators are detected:

```
((.*\+){2,}|(.*-){2,}|(.*\.){2,}|(.*%){2,}|(.*/){2,}|(.*\*){2,}).*
```

Comment: I copied that into regex101.com, and it returned an "unescaped deliminator" error

Comment: That will match two of those values after one another, rather than two in the same string, I see how i've been unclear though

Comment: Can you give examples of what should and should not be successful matches given a few inputs? I think that will help me throw an expression together.

Comment: 123.312.1 - successful, 123..12 - successful,  123.512 - unsuccessful

Comment: The plot thickens; firstly, good job, secondly, it needs to only flag two occurrences of the same operator, so +23232+ flags, +2323% doesn't

Comment: Try the above. I split each character into its own expression and OR-ed them. It appears to work well and succeed for the test cases.